# Тип сказуемого

Tags: сказуемые, синтаксис

Наш дом требует ремонта. Как думаете, уважаемые форумчане, какой тип сказуемого?

Comment: Людмила, поскольку в нашем споре вопрос остался открытым, я решил обратиться к Грамме.ру. Ответ см. ниже.

Answer (score 1):

Если учитывать, что знаменательная и полузнаменательная связка при определении типа сказуемого может быть заменена на отвлеченную, как напр.: **Мы вернулись домой усталые - ***Мы были усталые***; Он работал дворником - ***Он был дворником***; Он жил отшельником ***-*** Он был отшельником** -  я бы отнес к простому глагольному сказуемому. Вряд ли можно здесь заменить глагол ''требовать'' ( если считать его связкой), на отвлеченную. 
К тому же он не отвечает значениям связки.

Comment: Получается,дом что делает?-требует(сказуемое0. Чего?-ремонта(дополнение)Не странновато?

Answer (score 0):

Дом требует ремонта

ТРЕБОВАТЬ 5. (св. потребовать). чего. Нуждаться в чём-л., иметь потребность в чём-л. Т. ухода, внимания. Квартира требует ремонта. Болезнь требует лечения. Работа требует высокой квалификации.

Простое глагольное сказуемое, глагол "требовать" с сильным управлением, то есть его всегда дополняет существительное в Р.п.

Comment: Не поняла, как бы Вы подчеркнули сказуемое - только "требует" или "требует ремонта"?

Comment: Требует - сказуемое, ремонта - дополнение. Примеры ПГС (здесь в роли сказуемого выступают глагольно-именные описательные обороты, эквивалентные глаголу:  впасть в уныние (приуныть), оказать помощь (помочь), проявлять заботу (заботиться). Примеры дополнений (тесная связь со сказуемым при сильном управлении):  соблюдать правила, заняться спортом.

Comment: В названных Вами примерах действительно ПГС, "впасть в уныние"=приуныть - фразеологизм замещает глагол, но "требует ремонта" никак не заменить глаголом, хотя это тоже фразеологизм = ветхий, старый. Следовательно, это составное именное сказуемое.Наш дом каков?-требует ремонта(старый).

Answer (score 0):

- ### Ответ Граммы.ру

В этом споре произошло смешение разных признаков, лежащих в основе классификации типов сказуемого.
Формальным основанием для выделения составного именного сказуемого является наличие при глаголе именной формы, выраженной существительным в Им. или Тв. п., прилагательным в Им. или Тв. п., краткой форме, компаративе. Или возможность употребления этих форм (**ср.: Я был в восторге, но возможно: Я был грустным; Я остался в недоумении, но возможно: Я остался доволен).** См. об этом у А.М. Пешковского, который описывает разные формы присвязочного имени. С этой точки зрения в предложении **Наш дом требует ремонта сказуемое является простым глагольным (требует).**

**С точки зрения семантики составное именное сказуемое выражает признак неакциональный.** **В этом отношении фраза Наш дом требует ремонта близка по семантике к предложениям с именными предикатами.** В составном именном сказуемом неакциональный характер семантики обусловлен тем, что основное лексическое значение выражается именем, а связочный глагол имеет ослабленный характер, указывая на актуальный характер связи и на квалификацию связи между признаком и его носителем со стороны говорящего. 
**В предложении Наш дом требует ремонта неакциональный характер семантики предиката обусловлен не семантикой приглагольного имени, а семантикой подлежащего, которое имеет предметный, но неличный характер**. Неличное подлежащее не может являться источником целенаправленного действия, обозначаемого сказуемым, вызывая его переосмысление. В этом легко убедиться, если в приводимой Вами фразе заменить слово дом на, к примеру, слово мать; ср.: **Наша мать требует ремонта, где ﻿характеристика сказуемого не вызывает затруднений.** Указанное явление продемонстрировано в одной из работ Г.А. Золотовой на примере глагола вести: **Отец ведет ребенка домой - Тропинка ведет к реке - Ожирение ведет к болезням (в последнем примере глагол вести приобретает каузативное значение, так как подлежащее имеет событийный характер).**

Comment: Выходит, каждый остался при своём мнении, все правы. Только вот если это школьное задание, какого мнения должны придерживаться ученики? Вопрос.

Comment: К сожалению я не задавал этот вопрос им. А вы не сможете уточнить в той школе,  где Вы преподавали? Мне кажется, в простых школах, т.е. без лингвистического уклона, такие примеры не встречаются.